# Solving system of two inhomogenous ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have system of two ODEs,

$$
\dot{x} = \alpha (\beta-x)\\
\dot{y} = \gamma(x-y)
$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are constants.

I know how to solve the homogeneous system,

$$
\dot{x} = -x + 0.y\\
\dot{y} = \gamma x-\gamma y
$$

which in matrix form is,

$$
\mathbf{\dot{x}} = \mathbf{Ax}
$$

However, I'm not so sure how to deal with the $\alpha\beta$ term in the inhomogeneous system. I'm aware that we need to find a particular solution corresponding to the $\alpha\beta$ term.

Can someone kindly give pointers to materials on how to solve this?

Comment: The first equation is separable. Alternatively, rewrite your system in terms of the variables $u, v$, where $u = \beta - x$, $v = \beta - y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule of thumb to solving equations of the form: $$\overset{.}{x}+\alpha x=const.$$ is multiplying both sides by $e^{\alpha t}$ which creates a product rule on the left hand side.

In the case of the second equation you can basically do the same since you'll be multiplying an exponential by another exponential function, which is easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: solve at first the first equation $$x(t)=\beta+e^{-\alpha t}C$$